# How can I copy a git repo from a Makefile?

Tags: permissions, git, make, cp

I'm writing a Makefile to sync my local [dotfiles](https://github.com/EivindEE/dotfiles) with GitHub. I recently decided to also add my .vim folder to the repo. But when trying to copy the .vim folder I keep getting a Permission denied error.

The line in the Makefile that should copy the folder is:

```
@$(foreach file, $(FILES), echo "Copying $(BASH_DIR)$(file) to ."; cp -R $(BASH_DIR)$(file) . ; )
```

The permissions for the .vim folder is drwxr-xr-x, and the error message I get is:

```
cp: ./.vim/bundle/editorconfig-vim/.git/objects/pack/pack-bbb66dd84e2bdd3b05e19454b0800a928ecb94db.idx: Permission denied
cp: ./.vim/bundle/editorconfig-vim/.git/objects/pack/pack-bbb66dd84e2bdd3b05e19454b0800a928ecb94db.pack: Permission denied
cp: ./.vim/bundle/snipmate.vim/.git/objects/4d/e66757eebe4798eaaf02e3762a152d283eca81: Permission denied
cp: ./.vim/bundle/snipmate.vim/.git/objects/58/165f0e58211f8a5910df65414cc637651f046a: Permission denied
cp: ./.vim/bundle/snipmate.vim/.git/objects/6e/e90f3cfbd7c4956892da49896f62614448f851: Permission denied
cp: ./.vim/bundle/snipmate.vim/.git/objects/fc/161ff6515d405831c65c608d63627aa60c4066: Permission denied
cp: ./.vim/bundle/snipmate.vim/.git/objects/pack/pack-182ea16d08e5b471d5ce5f545f599f24ebe306cf.idx: Permission denied
cp: ./.vim/bundle/snipmate.vim/.git/objects/pack/pack-182ea16d08e5b471d5ce5f545f599f24ebe306cf.pack: Permission denied
cp: ./.vim/bundle/vim-jade/.git/objects/pack/pack-20254027167dcc621463c4454ed0fc539cf0b1da.idx: Permission denied
cp: ./.vim/bundle/vim-jade/.git/objects/pack/pack-20254027167dcc621463c4454ed0fc539cf0b1da.pack: Permission denied
cp: ./.vim/bundle/vim-markdown/.git/objects/pack/pack-b18aa89f38b322d622d05d969a9df41915bf9ea8.idx: Permission denied
cp: ./.vim/bundle/vim-markdown/.git/objects/pack/pack-b18aa89f38b322d622d05d969a9df41915bf9ea8.pack: Permission denied
```

Does anyone know how I can get this to work? Preferably without having to change permissions manually.

@vonbrand I am trying to add my vim setup to my dotfiles for easy access on other terminals. I am using [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) to handle my vim plugins. They are handled by cloning the plugins into the `.vim/bundles` directory. When I try to `cp -r` `.vim` into my dotfiles folder I get the error above. I'd like to find some solution for having these repos as a part of my dotfiles folder without having to manually change the permissions, as this would force me to repeat that process each time I decided to add or change a plugin. I don't know if the solution I'm looking for is passing some option to `cp`, or using some other tool for copying or syncing the `.vim` directory, or if `chown` is the only option I have.

`ls -ld ~/.vim/bundle/vim-jade/.git` returns `drwxr-xr-x  12 $USER  staff  408 Jan 21 15:26 ~/.vim/bundle/vim-jade/.git`

Comment: I am pretty sure this is unrelated to git and you have problems due to some wrong permissions, i.e. wrong user

Comment: Try `chmod -R u+rwX ~/.vim` such that you can write to all files/directories there. If it fails, you do not own all files and need to run `chown -R YOURUSERNAME ~/.vim` as root.

Comment: Please be more specific on what you are trying to get done. From the listing, `.vim` contains a bunch of git repositories on its own. Is the user doing the git stuff in .vim somebody other than you perhaps? What does e.g. `ls -ld .vim/bundle/vim-jade/.git` return?

Comment: Assuming your github directory is under `git` control, you don't want the `.git` directory inside `.vim`. You should exclude it. You could us the BASH builtin `cp -r !(exclude_me)` to do that.

Comment: It's really weird to be copying a `.git` directory. Are you sure you aren't looking for `git push`?

Comment: I know about `git push` and that wouldn't help me in this instance. I think the best option I've gotten at this point is from @htor and just exclude the .git folder. I had hoped to find a way to keep the repos so that my setup would be the same at all terminals, so that I could pull the latest changes. But I'll have to make due for now.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing [something very similar](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde) for some years now, and ended up using [symlinks](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/Makefile#L29) to avoid having to copy stuff back and forth. If you in addition want to have other repositories within the .vim directory you can easily do that with Git submodules (used for example for common makefile includes and shell scripts in [`mkgithub`](https://github.com/l0b0/mkgithub)).